# A flexible encoding scheme in oracle

Tags: character-encoding, oracle11g

I need an encoding scheme for a table which is flexible enough to support the english language but also languages such as russian, mandarin and arabic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tables in Oracle do not have encodings.

A database has a character set that drives the encoding of all the `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, `VARCHAR2`, and `CLOB` columns in the database.  If you want to support multiple languages, you would generally choose a Unicode based character set.  Presumably, that would be AL32UTF8.

A database also has a national character set.  That drives the encoding of all the `NCHAR`, `NVARCHAR`, `NVARCHAR2`, and `NCLOB` columns in the database.  If you have an existing database whose character set does not support all the characters you need and you cannot migrate the database to a Unicode character set because existing applications don't support it, you can add `NVARCHAR2` columns and use the national character set.  I don't believe it's possible to create a new 11g database whose national character set is not Unicode based (AL16UTF16 most likely) though it is possible to have such a beast if you have a legacy system that has been upgraded to 11g.  Using the national character set, however, generally requires more work than using the database character set-- various front-ends, for example, don't support national character set data cleanly and the API calls need to change when you're working with national character set data.  The UTF-16 character set also often takes more space than the UTF-8 character set-- UTF-16 uses either 2 or 4 bytes per character (the vast majority of characters require 2 bytes), UTF-8 uses between 1 and 4 bytes with English characters requiring 1 byte, most European characters requiring 2 bytes, and most Asian characters requiring 3 bytes.